# HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

Here is the error dat i'm getting while trying to make an authentication call to bigquery

```
HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/ClientId/datasets/samples/tables/natality?alt=json returned "Invalid project ID 'ClientId'. Project IDs must contain 6-63 lowercase letters, digits, or dashes. IDs must start with a letter and may not end with a dash.">
```

Here is my main.py

```
import httplib2
import os
from google.appengine.api import memcache
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from oauth2client.appengine import oauth2decorator_from_clientsecrets
from bqclient import BigQueryClient


PROJECT_ID = "########"  this is the Client Id 
DATASET = "samples"
TABLE = "natality"


CLIENT_SECRETS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
    'client_secrets.json')

http = httplib2.Http(memcache)
decorator = oauth2decorator_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRETS,
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/bigquery')

bq = BigQueryClient(http, decorator)

class MainHandler(webapp.RequestHandler):
    @decorator.oauth_required
    def get(self):
        self.response.out.write("Hello Dashboard!\n")
        modTime = bq.getLastModTime(PROJECT_ID, DATASET, TABLE)
        if modTime is not None:
            msg = 'Last mod time = ' + modTime
        else:
            msg = "Could not find last modification time.\n"
        self.response.out.write(msg)

application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
   ('/', MainHandler),
   (decorator.callback_path, decorator.callback_handler())
], debug=True)

def main():
   run_wsgi_app(application)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And here is the app.yaml

```
application: hellomydashboard
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.py
```

And here is the bqclient.py

```
import httplib2
from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.appengine import oauth2decorator_from_clientsecrets

class BigQueryClient(object):
    def __init__(self, http, decorator):
        """Creates the BigQuery client connection"""
        self.service = build('bigquery', 'v2', http=http)
        self.decorator = decorator

    def getTableData(self, project, dataset, table):
        decorated = self.decorator.http()
        return self.service.tables().get(projectId=project, datasetId=dataset,
            tableId=table).execute(decorated)

    def getLastModTime(self, project, dataset, table):
        data = self.getTableData(project, dataset, table)
        if data is not None and 'lastModifiedTime' in data:
            return data['lastModifiedTime']
        else:
            return None

    def Query(self, query, project, timeout_ms=10000):
        query_config = {
            'query': query,
            'timeoutMs': timeout_ms
        }
        decorated = self.decorator.http()
        result_json = (self.service.jobs()
                       .query(projectId=project, body=query_config)
                       .execute(decorated))

        return result_json
```

I also tried replacing the ClientId with Project Id as said in the error but it gives another error

```
HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/hellodashboard87/datasets/samples/tables/natality?alt=json returned "Not Found: Dataset hellodashboard87:samples">
```

I'm following the tutorial on this page
https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/dashboard#firstcall

Comment: The error message you've posted says it all: _"Invalid project ID 'ClientId'. Project IDs must contain 6-63 lowercase letters, digits, or dashes."_. Why don't you try changing `PROJECT_ID` to something like `project-id`, i.e., with only **lowercase** letters, digits or dashes.

Comment: Ya i did try it with the project Id also but it giving another error HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/hellodashboard87/datasets/samples/tables/natality?alt=json returned "Not Found: Dataset hellodashboard87:samples">

Comment: You can try and use https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/bigquery/v2/bigquery.tables.get to test to see if your inputs are accurate. You can more easily mess around with the API via this method to test your input values quickly.

Comment: well i tried as u said but it shows------ error    404 Not Found
 
- Show headers -
  
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "notFound",
    "message": "Not Found: Dataset 440265227336:samples"
   }
  ],
  "code": 404,
  "message": "Not Found: Dataset 440265227336:samples"
 }
}

Comment: @someone1 it also showing Request GET https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/440265227336/datasets/samples/tables/natality?key={YOUR_API_KEY}

Authorization:  Bearer ya29.AHES6ZQDddqS_qBwjpn3ngTaaYf33oUScSW2vWtTCYR4z9sGErxX
X-JavaScript-User-Agent:  Google APIs Explorer                        do i need an API key for this.If so how to do this.No field to input api key

Comment: @jade make sure the `Authorize requests using OAuth 2.0:` is set to "On" on the top right corner of the page so your calls are authenticated. Afterwards, if you are getting errors, then your setup is incorrect, verify that you correctly setup a project ID and are inputting the values correctly. You can find the Project ID by going to https://code.google.com/apis/console/, it is listed under `Project ID`. You get your Dataset IDs and Table IDs here: https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/

Comment: i have turned the OAuth 2.0 ON but still getting the error

Comment: i wanted to clarify one thing that the Dataset that i'm trying to access is from sample Datasets.I havent done anything to link them with my project in any way.Do i need to do anything to access those datasets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to use the public data sets offered by Google's BigQuery, use the following parameters:

**Project ID**: `publicdata`

**Dataset ID**: `samples`

**Table ID**: `natality` (or whatever you want to use)

In order to use any data sets that you own, switch your Project ID to the one found in the API Console dashboard.

Comment: so in order to use a public data, i dont need to create my own project or anything on google api console.But in dat case how would i authenticate

Comment: your current method of authentication should work, are you receiving any errors?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use BigQuery, you must create a project in the [APIs Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) that has BigQuery enabled (I'm assuming you have done this). Once you've created the project, you'll be able to get the **project number** from the URL, e.g.

```
https://code.google.com/apis/console/#project:12345XXXXXXX
```

In the example, the project number is `12345XXXXXXX` and this is the value you would use for `PROJECT_ID`.

Comment: well i did exactly the same thing, but still getting this error saying Invalid Project ID

Comment: And you have created the project correctly in the APIs Console? What value are you using for PROJECT_ID?

Comment: I was mistaken, please see my edited answer. You'll want the project number from the project, not the client ID (though the project number often appears in the client ID).

Comment: still getting another error  HttpError: <HttpError 404 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/440265227336/datasets/samples/tables/natality?alt=json returned "Not Found: Dataset 440265227336:samples">

Comment: You're encountering a different class of issue now, it's definitely authenticating correctly. You'll need to adjust `DATASET` and `TABLE` to match those in your project.

Comment: well i'm actually new to this whole thing.So i would like to clarify one thing.Before doing this i assumed that the dataset and tables that i'm using are already there.I didn't create any dataset or tables.i'm following this tutorial  and i doesn't say anywhere to create any dataset or tables https://developers.google.com/bigquery/articles/dashboard#firstcall and i assumed that the DATASET = "samples"
TABLE = "natality" are already there as sample databases.Is it so?If not how to add these to my project.

Comment: See the other answer for accessing public data sets. Use `publicdata` as the value for `PROJECT_ID`.